# How do I make this image slider to slide more than once when clicked, using Jquery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Jquery/JavaScript snippet I'm working on.

Basically it's a Object Orientated image slider. See the code on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/eloduj/3/edit#html,live

The problem is that when I click the slider navigation controls it only slides once in each direction! How can I get this to work properly as there are 4 image DIVs?

Any help would be appreciated greatly, Thank you

**ANSWER (After some help from rdcmk) Sharing is caring**

JS

```
var cn = {
    hero : function(r,rc,lx,rx){
        rc=$(rc),rcw=rc.width(),rca=rc.size(),rw=rcw*rca;$(r).css({'width':rw});
        $(lx).click(function(){n=$(r).position().left-rcw; $(r).animate({left:(n<-rw+rcw?0:n)+'px'},500);});
        $(rx).click(function(){n=$(r).position().left+rcw; $(r).animate({left:(n>0?-rw+rcw:n)+'px'},500);});
    }
}
$(function(){
    cn.hero('#reel', '#reel div', '#reel-left', '#reel-right');
});
```

HTML & CSS

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; outline:none; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#wrap { width:1024px; margin:0 auto; }

#hero { border:1px dashed lime; position:relative; width:1022px; height:304px; overflow:hidden }
#hero #reel { border:1px dashed red; position:absolute; height:302px; left:0; }
#hero #reel div { width: 1018px; height:300px; float:left; }
#reel-controls { position: absolute; z-index:10; }

 <div id="hero">
        <div id="reel">
            <div id="pic1" style="background-color:#C3F"></div>
            <div id="pic2" style="background-color:#0F9"></div>
            <div id="pic3" style="background-color:#999"></div>
            <div id="pic3" style="background-color:#6CC"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="reel-controls">
            <span id="reel-left">left</span>
            <span id="reel-right">right</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it: http://jsbin.com/eloduj/14/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

the answer is quite simple. You are currently doing something equivalent to `x=3` while you want `x=x+3`..

do something like this (pseudo-code)

```
$(leftCtrl).click(function(){
                  var currentLeft = $(reel).offset().left;
                  $(reel).animate({ left: currentLeft-reelChildWidth }, 500 );
        });

        $(rightCtrl).click(function(){
                  var currentlLeft = $(reel).offset().left;
                  $(reel).animate({ left: currentLleft+reelChildWidth }, 500 );
```

let me know if this is good enough or if you need a running example.

Comment: ...Thank you for your help...it's kind of working now but the calculations are off by some. Any ideas?

Comment: ...I think I'll be needing that running example